# Relationship between variables

Tags: c++

I'm facing this problem in programming it says that if jack knows john and john know mark, then jack should know mark
the input is like this

```
1 - 3
3 - 4
1 - 4
```

1 knows 3 and 3 knows 4 so 1 knows 4, the answer is yes otherwise if the third line isn't there the answer is false because there's no connection between these three persons.
How can I implement this in c++ to make a connection between these three (on large inputs).

Comment: Look up "breadth-first search" or "depth-first search." This is essentially a graph search in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple if you know c++;
you just have to make a friend List of every person, then you can make a function

```
bool isFriend(person1,person2)
```

Which will return true if person1 and person2 knows each other, then you can make relationship of 3rd person if he knows any of them he'll know both of them as your requirement.

To make friend list you can use jagged array data structure and adjacency list with link list;

Comment: It'll more simple if you perform all it at insertion of data.